# Mediawiki - Force IE10 to Document mode IE8

Tags: types, internet-explorer-8, document, mediawiki, doctype

ive a Problem with sematic media wiki and the WYSIWYG Extension.
In Document Mode IE10 and IE10 the Editor destroys the semantic tags - but everything works finde in document mode IE8.

So my question: How can I tell the IE to use this Doc mode?

The Browser Mode doesnt matter - just the document mode.
Compatibility View too - just neeed Doc Type IE8 :D.

I just found this:

[MediaWiki Manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgDocType)

but this isnt actual - the page says it is removed in actual Versions.

Searched for a Long time, only found Solutions without Mediawiki :D.

Would be very appreciated if someone could help me out here

EDIT:

I think  wgDocType is the solution.
but the Default value is: 
    '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'

how exactly can i set document mode to IE8 :D?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue.

in outputpage.php
I changed the methodː

public function getHeadLinksArray( $addContentType = false )

i changed

```
if ( $wgHtml5 ) {
$tags['meta-charset'] = Html::element( 'meta', array( 'charset' => 'UTF-8' ) );         
);
```

to

```
if ( $wgHtml5 ) {
$tags['meta-charset'] = Html::element( 'meta', array( 'charset' => 'UTF-8' ) );
$tags['meta-http-equiv'] = Html::element( 'meta', array( 'http-equiv' => 'X-UA-Compatible' ,'content' => 'IE=EmulateIE8' ) 
);
```

works perfect :D